# How can Thread.Join() in .NET return before the thread has terminated?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, websocket

I have a process that spawns 2 threads. One thread reads from a web socket, and the other writes to the same web socket. Once everything is initialized and the web socket has connected, the main thread blocks on the 2 threads it created in the following function:

```
public void BlockUntilThreadsAreDone()
{
    if (_incomingThread.IsAlive)
        _incomingThread.Join();
    if (_outgoingThread.IsAlive)
        _outgoingThread.Join();
}
```

Everything runs fine for a while. But after several minutes, I discovered that the main thread will return from this function. No exceptions are thrown, and I don't see any unusual logging. The function simply returns because the `Thread.Join()` calls returned.

I modified the function to wait on an event that both threads will set when they are shutting down as follows:

```
private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _messagingComplete = new(false);

public void BlockUntilThreadsAreDone()
{
    if (_incomingThread.IsAlive)
        _incomingThread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine($"Incoming thread state={_incomingThread.ThreadState}");

    if (_outgoingThread.IsAlive)
       _outgoingThread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine($"Outgoing thread state={_outgoingThread.ThreadState}");

    _messagingComplete.Wait(_cancellationToken);
}
```

The thread objects are created like this

```cs
_incomingMessageThread = new(HandleIncomingMessages) { Name = "Incoming" };
_outgoingMessageThread = new(HandleOutgoingMessages) { Name = "Outgoing" };
```

```
private async void HandleIncomingMessages()
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PapiClient HandleIncomingMessages starting");

        do
        {
            try
            {
                Message? message = await ReceiveIncomingMessageAsync();
                // Handle each message asynchronously so we can keep receiving more messages
                _ = Task.Run(
                    () =>
                    {
                        HandleIncomingMessage(message);
                    },
                    _cancellationToken
                );
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception while handling messages: {ex}");
            }
        } while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && Connected);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
    finally
    {
        _messagingComplete.Set();
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"PapiClient HandleIncomingMessages finishing: cancel={_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested}, connected={Connected}"
        );
    }
}
```

Now the code works as I would expect (i.e., the function only returns once we're done processing). Technically it's not the same since this returns once the first thread completes, but that's close enough for my purposes.

Interestingly, I see that a few minutes after the process started, both threads will be eventually log that their state is `ThreadState.Stopped`.  The threads most definitely are not stopped, though, because I can tell the process continues to send and receive data over the web socket, and there are no other threads created to work with the web socket.  In addition, all the normal processing that happens when the threads terminate doesn't occur at that point.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=net-7.0#system-threading-thread-join) says that `Join` "blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates."  [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?view=net-7.0) also says that "a thread can never leave the Stopped state."

I am baffled. Why would `Thread.Join()` return and a thread indicate its state is `Stopped` when it most definitely has not stopped?

I suspect this might have something to do with networking and/or web sockets in particular.  I ran a packet capture while this was happening, and I noticed a few milliseconds before the problem occurred, the websocket [sends an unsolicited PONG message](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.WebSockets/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L566). The unsolicited PONG isn't a problem by itself, but those are only sent every 30 seconds, so it seems unusual that the spurious `Thread.Join()` would happen just a few milliseconds after [a timer wakes up and sends the PONG message](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.WebSockets/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L171).

I couldn't find an issue about this on the [.NET core github issues list](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues).  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it's not watching the thread you think it should be watching. But to be honest, it's unclear why you are using threads anyway, why not use the newer and more efficient `Task` and `async` setup?

Comment: From the [WebSocket docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket), "Exactly one send and one receive is supported on each WebSocket object in parallel. Issuing multiple sends or multiple receives at the same time (for example, without awaiting, or from multiple threads without synchronization) is not supported and will result in an undefined behavior."  Creating dedicated threads with controlled handoff of data to/from them seemed like a good approach.  If WebSocket didn't have thse constraints,, then a different approach might have been clearer.

Comment: Regarding "not watching the thread I think," it's hard for me to imagine how that could be possible.  I am only explicitly creating 2 threads, and both of those are both `readonly` class variables assigned in the constructor.  Unless .NET is doing a bait and switch on me, I'm looking at the right threads.

```C#
_incomingThread = new(HandleIncomingMessages) { Name = "Incoming" };
_outgoingThread = new(HandleOutgoingMessages) { Name = "Outgoing" };
```

Comment: Show the code. If possible a [mcve].

Comment: The code in question is here: https://github.com/paranext/paranext-core/blob/main/c-sharp/MessageTransports/PapiClient.cs.  It will take a while to produce a separate, minimal example that I can test and verify it has the same result.  Since I have a workaround for now I don't have the time to do that.  I was hoping someone here would know about a bug or some corner case I did not know.

Comment: By the looks of things, it might be it's overrunning the timeout on `Join`. I think you need some more debugging with breakpoints. I still think you are doing things wrong by managing threads explicitly. You could use `Task.Run(() => HandleIncomingMessages())` to the same effect. This has nothing to do with the restrictions on websockets, it's the same loop being run.

Comment: I'm running `Join()` without a timeout.

Comment: While I understand I could write the code differently, that isn't the question I'm asking.

Comment: @Matt `that isn't the question I'm asking.` that's the correct answer though - don't do it like this. Even if you insist on using low-level threads, .NET offers far better and faster *high*-level constructs. At best you'd be wasting threads, waiting for something to happen. If you want a producer and consumer to run independently, you can use a `Channel<T>` as a truly asynchronous queue. No explicit locking necessary. Channels use `async/await` though which means your own code needs to be asynchronous. There are even higher level pipeline constructs in Dataflow like ActionBlock, TransformBlock

Comment: @Matt as for the exact question, all [WebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=net-7.0) methods are asynchronous so the application either blocks on them or neglects to await them. .NET won't return unless the thread is done, which means something else is going on, in the application code itself. Please post that code

Comment: `there are no other threads created to work with the web socket` that's incorrect because all WebSocket methods are asynchronous. Even if the application uses `SendAsync().Wait()`, part of SendAsync's code will still run on a threadpool thread and maybe use IO completion ports. That's why using explicit threads is a bad idea - it wastes extra threads when a lot of the work is already running on pooled, reusable threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your repo on Github (by the way your question should really be self-contained), the two functions `HandleOutgoingMessages` and `HandleIncomingMessages` are marked `async void`. Which means as soon as they hit their first `await` they are going to end, and post the continuation to the threadpool.

You seem to be expecting that the thread they are on will somehow pause, and pick up when the `await` continuation happens. This is not true. Your thread ends, and the threadpool will pick it up.

This is essentially a confusion between threads and tasks. You are mostly using tasks and async, I suggest you stick with that, and therefore use `Task.Run` to offload the `Handle` functions.

You need the following changes

```cs
private readonly Task _incomingMessageThread;
private readonly Task _outgoingMessageThread;
```

```cs
private async Task HandleIncomingMessages()
{
```

```cs
private async Task HandleOutgoingMessages()
{
```

Remove the lines in the constructor beginning `_incomingMessageThread =`  and `_outgoingMessageThread =`.

Replace the lines `_incomingMessageThread.Start(); _outgoingMessageThread.Start();` with

```cs
_incomingMessageThread = Task.Run(HandleIncomingMessages, _cancellationToken);
_outgoingMessageThread = Task.Run(HandleOutgoingMessages, _cancellationToken);
```

At various points when you need to wait for the threads to finish, just do

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(_incomingMessageThread, _outgoingMessageThread);
```

You do not need to check whether they have finished, they will always have finished after that.

Alternatively

```cs
try
{
    await Task
        .WhenAll(_incomingMessageThread, _outgoingMessageThread)
        .WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT));
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    if (!_incomingMessageThread.IsCompleted)
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming task not stopping");
    if (!_outgoingMessageThread.IsCompleted)
        Console.WriteLine("Outgoing task not stopping");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed thoughts.  I appreciate it!

I follow what you're saying, but this part at the beginning doesn't align with all the data: "Which means as soon as they hit their first await they are going to end, and post the continuation to the threadpool."  The threads were sending a LOT of data back and forth over the websocket for minutes before they finished, so the dedicated threads were not ending after they hit await (which aligns with a send or receive of data).  I can see how mixing async/await and explicit threading could lead to strange interplays, though.

Comment: I can only imagine that for whatever reason the `await`s were happening synchronously, presumably because the data was already waiting. My point stands: the use of threads here makes no sense.

Comment: You've highlighted the root cause here which is what I was searching for.  The use of `async` functions with a ThreadStart at least gives the *possibility* of the thread ending at an `await` within the function. That possibility is probably never desired.